# Why insertBefore, on this scenario, delete my element?

Tags: jquery, html

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/yp9LT/2/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="try" id="try1">1</div>
<div class="try" id="try2">2</div>
<div class="try" id="try3">3</div>
```

## jQuery

```
var ImmagineDrag=$('#try3');
var ImmagineDrop=$('#try2');

var swap1 = ImmagineDrag.index();
var swap2 = ImmagineDrop.index();

ImmagineDrag.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap2));
ImmagineDrop.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap1));
```

why the div `try2` will be removed from the DOM?

Comment: could be a index problem, try this: `ImmagineDrop.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap1)); ImmagineDrag.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap2));`

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/yp9LT/3/)

Comment: That's because you are inserting the element before itself.

Comment: the div indexes are changing u can't predefine them

Comment: I suggest you compare `swap1 == ImmagineDrop.index()` after the first `.insertBefore`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to swap items 2 and 3, you may do this :

```
$('#try3').insertBefore($('#try2'));
```

There is no reason here to be more complex. If you'd wanted to swap items 1 and 3, you could do

```
$('#try3').insertBefore($('#try1'));
$('#try1').insertAfter($('#try2'));
```

You just put the item where you want it to be.

**EDIT :**

I made this function which swaps 2 elements that are childs of the same element (we could generalize but this would need more tests : last child, only child, etc.) :

```
function swap($a, $b) { // a and b are (different) $jquery elements
    if ($b.index()<$a.index()) {
       var t = $a;
       $a = $b; $b = t;        
    }
    if ($b.index()==$a.index()+1) {
        $b.insertBefore($a);
    } else {
        var $c = $a.next();
        $a.insertBefore($b);
        $b.insertBefore($c);
    }
}
```

It can be tested here : http://jsfiddle.net/ferJR/

Comment: Not really! If I try to swap try1 and try3 with your code, I miss one posizion.

Comment: I tried it before answering : http://jsfiddle.net/hcnUR/ Isn't that a swap of 1 and 3 ?

Comment: Well, I made a function that can use all elements I pass! What do you think about? Can I improve it? http://jsfiddle.net/yp9LT/5/

Comment: Are you trying to swap objects known by their indices or by their id ? Do you want swap(index1, index2) or swap(id1, id2) ?

Comment: See edit : I've made a function swapping two jquery elements.

Answer (score 0):

`ImmagineDrop.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap1));`
At this time, `$('.try').eq(swap1)` is `ImmagineDrop` itself.

So it is same with `ImmagineDrop.insertBefore(ImmagineDrop);`.

When you insert an element before the element itself, it will cause it be detached from the document.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the why :

```
var ImmagineDrag=$('#try3');
var ImmagineDrop=$('#try2');

var swap1 = ImmagineDrag.index();
var swap2 = ImmagineDrop.index();
//at this point:
//  swap1 contains the value: 2
//  swap2 contains the value: 1

// $('.try').eq(swap2)  selects  $('#try2')
ImmagineDrag.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap2));
// now $('#try3') has been inserted before '#try2'
// the order is now: try1, try3, try2

// the order of the nodes have changed :
//    swap1 is still 2,
//    so $('.try').eq(swap1) selects the third element
//    which is now '#try2'
// this action tries to insert '#try2' before itself !
ImmagineDrop.insertBefore($('.try').eq(swap1));
// hence your problem...
```

As to how to fix it :
you could use a placeholder

```
function swap(node1, node2){ //2 nodes
     $placeHolder = $('<span>').insertBefore(node1);
     $(node1).insertBefore(node2);
     $(node2).insertBefore($placeHolder);
     $placeHolder.remove();
}
```

but be aware that such a function does not work correctly if node1 == node2, or if node1 is a descendant of node2.